# Amazon S3 Java API Only Downloads 50 Objects

Tags: java, amazon-s3

This was giving me a major head-ache, so I thought I'd post the easy solution.
My issue was that when using the Java API for Amazon's S3, I could only download 50 objects before it would mysteriously time out. The code looked something like this:

```
int counter = 0;
AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(propertiesFile);
while(objectList.isTruncated()){
for(S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectList.getObjectSummaries()){
    System.out.println(++counter);
    S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, objectSummary.getKey()));
//do stuff
}
}
```

It would run and process everything fine for exactly 50 objects, and then time out.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, the main issue is that I had declared s3 as `AmazonS3Client s3`. It should have looked like:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(propertiesFile);
```

Just in case anyone else runs into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully while you may callling getObject to download it, you are not closing the InputStream. which is optioned by calling getObject(); you have to close InputStream after dealing with each object.

more details read it : http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObject(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Scala developers, here it is recursive function to execute a ***full scan and map*** of the contents of an AmazonS3 bucket using the official [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/)

```scala
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.{S3ObjectSummary, ObjectListing, GetObjectRequest}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.{collectionAsScalaIterable => asScala}

def map[T](s3: AmazonS3Client, bucket: String, prefix: String)(f: (S3ObjectSummary) => T) = {

  def scan(acc:List[T], listing:ObjectListing): List[T] = {
    val summaries = asScala[S3ObjectSummary](listing.getObjectSummaries())
    val mapped = (for (summary <- summaries) yield f(summary)).toList

    if (!listing.isTruncated) mapped.toList
    else scan(acc ::: mapped, s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing))
  }

  scan(List(), s3.listObjects(bucket, prefix))
}
```

To invoke the above curried `map()` function, simply pass the already constructed (and properly initialized) AmazonS3Client object (refer to the official [AWS SDK for Java API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html)), the bucket name and the prefix name in the first parameter list. Also pass the function `f()` you want to apply to map each object summary in the second parameter list.

For example

```scala
val tuple = map(s3, bucket, prefix)(s => (s.getKey, s.getOwner, s.getSize))
```

will return the full list of `(key, owner, size)` tuples in that bucket/prefix

or

```scala
val totalSize = map(s3, "bucket", "prefix")(s => s.getSize).sum
```

will return the total size of its content (note the additional `sum()` folding function applied at the end of the expression ;-)

You can combine `map()` with many other functions as you would normally approach by [Monads in Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29)